# How to display a particular tab from another form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I am working on a vb.net project in VS 2010 that has multiple forms. I have, lets say, Form1 with a Button and Form2 with a TabControl.

How do i display a particular tab(eg.tab2 or tab3) when the user clicks on the button from form1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the selected tab of a `TabControl` you can use [`SelectTab`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecttab(v=vs.110).aspx) method or [`SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your tab control.

Controls of a form are not accessible from outside of the form by default. You can let access to a control of a form by setting the [`Modifiers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233630(v=vs.110).aspx) property of control to `Public` and [`GenerateMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233630(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true`.

So go to designer of `Form2`, select your tab control, in properties window, set `GenerateMember` to `true` and set `Modifier` to be `Public`. Then you can access your tab control from `Form1`:

```
Dim f as New Form2()
f.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1 'It selects second tab
f.ShowDialog()
```

**Note**

In general as a good design guideline it's better not to expose your forms controls. In such case it's better to create property or method in your `Form2` and use it to get/set selected tab of `Form2` from `Form1`. For example you can see Munawar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36058252/3110834).

Comment: i want to display the  **TabPage** present in the tabcontrol.

Comment: Thank you for you help sir.

Comment: So follow the instructions in the answer. What's the problem? It shows your form 2 ans sets the active tab of your tab control.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a public method on form with tab controls

```
Public void TabSelection( int tabIndex)
{

MyTabControl.SelectedTab =MyTabControl.TabPages[tabIndex];
}
```

VB.Net Code:

```
 Public Sub TabSelection(ByVal tabIndex As Integer)
        MyTabControl.SelectedTab = MyTabControl.TabPages(tabIndex)
    End Sub
```

Call above method from button click handler from other forms.